# TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation in Shopify

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify, shopify-api

I do [shopify react tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/build-your-user-interface-with-polaris).
But MyApp shown this error.

```
./node_modules/@shopify/polaris/dist/styles.css
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
```

How can I fix it?

| Package | version |
| --- | --- |
| Node | 15.9.0 |
| npm | 7.5.3 |
| yarn | 1.22.10 |
| @shopify/koa-shopify-auth | ^3.2.8 |
| @shopify/polaris | ^6.0.1 |
| @zeit/next-css | ^1.0.1 |
| dotenv | ^8.2.0 |
| isomorphic-fetch | ^3.0.0 |
| koa | ^2.13.1 |
| koa-session | ^6.1.0 |
| next | ^10.0.7 |
| react | ^17.0.1 |
| react-dom | ^17.0.1 |
| webpack | ^5.23.0 |

This is my code.

```
import App from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { AppProvider } from '@shopify/polaris';
import translations from '@shopify/polaris/locales/en.json';
import '@shopify/polaris/dist/styles.css';

class MyApp extends App {
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Head>
                    <title>Sample App</title>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                </Head>
                <AppProvider i18n={ translations }>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </AppProvider>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the next.config.js file and it will work as expected. The tutorial is old. Next.js supports css in v 10.